# UIView real frame in iOS7

Tags: ios6, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I need to add some view in iOS 7. And in the same time my project have to work on iOS 6.

[image]

How can I do it programmacly? I want to see the same position of "i"-button on 2 versions of app.

Comment: Umm... what? How do you expect to see it if it's behind a table view?

Comment: @Kevin , sorry, "ahead".

Comment: iOS 7 is still under NDA until tomorrow when they release it to public.

Comment: @MaxHasADHD That's not our problem.

Comment: @MaxHasADHD it's 1:14 PM, 18.09

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you trying to put the segmented control in the header?  Why do you expect different behavior between different operating systems?  Even if they look different, you should expect similar behavior.

Comment: @timurbernikowich what does the time have to do with it?:P I was JS, its technically under NDA still until its out for everyone and docs and such are accessible by non-paying iOS dev's.

Comment: @NealEhardt I remade my question, it has to be clear to understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a category I put on a ViewController. It might not be the smartest method but it works for my views. All my apps build the UI's programatically. If you set the frame of a view to this after it has been loaded, it will behave the same in iOS 7 as in earlier versions. The code isn't kludgy in that it doesn't rely on the version rather the characteristics of the superview. I'm open to any comments.

```
@implementation UIViewController (effectiveContentFrame)

// determine frame size and offset to get the max frame we can get for the current view and orientation
// needed this after the introduction of iOS 7 where frames are handled slightly differently
// note: it uses the different heights/widths at the current rotation


/*
 iOS 6 portrait
  application Frame: = (0.000000,20.000000) 320.000000x460.000000 )
  superview Frame = (0.000000,20.000000) 320.000000x460.000000 )

 iOS7 portrait
  application Frame: = (0.000000,20.000000) 320.000000x460.000000 )
  superview Frame = (0.000000,0.000000) 320.000000x480.000000 )

 */
- (CGRect) effectiveContentFrame
    {
    CGRect rect;
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    CGRect statusBarFrame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
    CGFloat statusBarHeight = 0.;

    rect = self.view.superview.frame; // the frame will be relative to the superview. Note in iOS6 the root superview frame includes the

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))
        {
        rect.size.height += rect.origin.y; // total height
        statusBarHeight = statusBarFrame.size.height;
        }
    else
        {
        rect.size.height += rect.origin.x; // total height
        statusBarHeight = statusBarFrame.size.width;
        }

    CGFloat extraHeight = 0;    // this is going to be how much extra height we have to take off of the total height of the frame,
                                // which is going to be the status bar+navbar+toolbar heights
    CGFloat topHeight = 0;      // this is the height of the stuff before the frame, which we are going to use as an offset


    if (![UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden)
        extraHeight += statusBarHeight;
   if (!self.navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden)
        extraHeight += self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    topHeight = extraHeight;
    if (!self.navigationController.toolbar.isHidden)
        extraHeight += self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height;

    rect.origin.y = topHeight - rect.origin.y;  // in iOS6 the status bar and navbar is already included in the origin but not in iOS7 .
    if (rect.origin.y < 0)
        rect.origin.y = 0;


    rect.size.height -= extraHeight;    // subtract status/nav and toolbar heights from the total height left in the superview

    return rect;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that type of Top Bar of your main view is Translucent Navigation Bar. Try to change it in IB to Opaque Navigation Bar.

I have had the same problem when I upgraded to the new xCode. I think this is because in older version opaque type was first in the list and now translucent on it's place.

Also, you can try `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` in your UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 5 IB you can find iOS 6 / 7 deltas. All that you need is just adjust them.
[image: Example]

Comment: It's interesting, but it's not solution. I'd like to create category, where i can simply write `[someView visibleRect]` and get frame without surface under navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in C#

```cs
    public static RectangleF GetUsableContentSize(this UIViewController viewController) {
        RectangleF rect;
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation;
        RectangleF statusBarFrame = UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame;
        float statusBarHeight = 0.0f;

        var view = viewController.View;

        if (view.Superview != null)
            rect = view.Superview.Frame; // the frame will be relative to the superview. Note in iOS6 the root superview frame includes the
        else
            rect = view.Frame;


        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown)
        {
            rect.Height += rect.Y; // total height
            statusBarHeight = statusBarFrame.Height;
        }
        else
        {
            rect.Height += rect.X; // total height
            statusBarHeight = statusBarFrame.Width;
        }

        float extraHeight = 0;    // this is going to be how much extra height we have to take off of the total height of the frame,
        // which is going to be the status bar+navbar+toolbar heights
        float topHeight = 0;      // this is the height of the stuff before the frame, which we are going to use as an offset


        if (!UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarHidden)
            extraHeight += statusBarHeight;

        if (!viewController.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Hidden)
            extraHeight += viewController.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame.Height;

        topHeight = extraHeight;
        if (!viewController.NavigationController.Toolbar.Hidden)
            extraHeight += viewController.NavigationController.Toolbar.Frame.Height;

        rect.Y = topHeight - rect.Y;  // in iOS6 the status bar and navbar is already included in the origin but not in iOS7 .
        if (rect.Y < 0)
            rect.Y = 0;


        rect.Size.Height -= extraHeight;    // subtract status/nav and toolbar heights from the total height left in the superview

        return rect;
    }
```